Error while working with PostgreSQL 'ascii_lettersdigitspunctuation
import psycopg2
from passlib.hash import bcrypt
#from config import host, user, password, db_name

try:
    # connect to the existing database
    connection = psycopg2.connect(
        host="127.0.0.1",
        user="user",
        password="123a",
        database="postgres3"   
    )
    connection.autocommit = True

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(
            "SELECT version();"
        )

    print(f"Server version: {cursor.fetchone()}")

    # Generate a strong password
    from passlib import pwd
    strong_password = pwd.genword(length=15, charset='ascii_letters' + 'digits' + 'punctuation')

    # Hash the password using bcrypt
    hashed_password = bcrypt.hash(strong_password)

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(
            "CREATE TABLE users(id serial PRIMARY KEY, username varchar(50) NOT NULL, password varchar(255) NOT NULL);"
        )

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(
            "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ('admin', %s);",
            [hashed_password]
        )

        print(f"[INFO] Data was successfully inserted, generated password: {strong_password}")

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(
           "SELECT * FROM users;"
        )

        print("User info from the database:")
        for row in cursor.fetchall():
            print(row)

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(
            "DROP TABLE users;"
        )

        print("[INFO] Table was deleted")

except Exception as ex:
    print("[INFO] Error while working with PostgreSQL", ex)
finally:
    if connection:
        connection.close()
        print("[INFO] PostgreSQL connection closed")

code error:
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Ardor\Desktop\курсовая 2\main.py", line 24, in <module>

    strong_password = pwd.genword(length=15, charset='ascii_letters' + 'digits' + 'punctuation')

  File "C:\Users\Ardor\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\passlib\pwd.py", line 494, in genword

    gen = WordGenerator(length=length, entropy=entropy, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Ardor\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\passlib\pwd.py", line 392, in __init__
    chars = default_charsets[charset]

KeyError: 'ascii_lettersdigitspunctuation'

The code should create a strong password and encrypt it and enter it into the database. The postgresql server is running, but it does not connect to it and gives an error. What could be causing this and how can I fix it? Changing the encoding in the database did not help.

This problem has nothing to do with PostgreSQL - the error is quite specific: the passlib.pwd.genword call does not recognize what you are passing to the charset parameter.  And that makes sense - even if the individual literal strings you are passing to it would be recognized separately (and they are not valid values either) - what sense would it make just to  "glue" then together by concatenating?  If the parameter where to accept different charset strings in order to create a superset including all of then, it would make sense for it to get an iterable of those strings - how would it even parse the 'ascii_lettersdigitspunctuation' you are passing it?
That said, I quote bellow the documentation for wordgen charset parameter. You likely will want to use ascii_72:

:param charset:
The predefined character set to draw from (if not specified by **chars**).
There are currently four presets available:

* ``"ascii_62"`` (the default) -- all digits and ascii upper & lowercase letters.
  Provides ~5.95 entropy per character.

* ``"ascii_50"`` -- subset which excludes visually similar characters
  (``1IiLl0Oo5S8B``). Provides ~5.64 entropy per character.

* ``"ascii_72"`` -- all digits and ascii upper & lowercase letters,
  as well as some punctuation. Provides ~6.17 entropy per character.

* ``"hex"`` -- Lower case hexadecimal.  Providers 4 bits of entropy per character.



I'm guessing the OP was trying to pass string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation to the char parameter.

in this case, two wrongs make an even greater error, not a right! :-)  (I mean, literals instead of string module attributes, and passing them to charset instead of chars)

Changing to ascii_72 solved the problem, thank you very much and delete + 'digits' + 'punctuation'
